# How to deal with the order of queries to not violate unique constraint

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

Suppose I have two entities, `News` and `Tag`. They have an one-to-many relationship.
Also I have a unique constraint on the tags table `('news_id', 'name')`.

Now my current state is:

```
tags
---------------------
id | news_id | tag
---------------------
1  |       1 | world
2  |       1 | event
```

If I do:

```
$em->remove($tag2);
$em->persist(new Tag($tag2->getNews(), 'event'));
```

I get `Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry` because doctrine tries to insert before removing the old entity. The same happens when I do update/remove. Is it possible to tell doctrine to remove the old entity first? Or is there a better solution?

**Another example:**

A simple table:

```
tags
---------------------
id | tag
---------------------
1  | world
2  | event
```

UNIQUE constraint is set for `tag` column.

Now I do:

```
$tags = $em->getRepository('Tag')->findAll();
$tempName = $tags[0]->getName();
$tags[0]->setName($tags[1]->getName());
$tags[1]->setName($tempName);
```

And get the same error because it tries to update the first tag with the 'event' value and there's already a duplicate.

PS: I know I can call `flush` twice, but it's a bad idea.

Comment: An update doesn't work? I think you should focus on trying to perform an update, deleting before inserting seems not logical.

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to do? You should have an association table between your News And Tag. In your database, `id` seems to be useless, is it used as a primary key or foreign key elsewhere?

Comment: @n.1 Why is performing two basic operations not logical? The `id` column is just for clarity's sake. And I prefer using them for primary keys instead of natural keys. I think the question is more complicated and can be rephrased as following. Suppose you have two entites of the same class. They both have `name` property. It has a unique constraint. Now you want to swap (e1.name = e2.name, e2.name = old e1.name) their names. If you try to do it with Doctrine, you'll get a duplicate entry error on the first query when flushing.

Comment: Ok, now I understand your problem. I think the problem is that you remove `$tag2` then re-use it `$tag2->getNews()`. Is it cascading? I mean, the `remove()` may not unbind the news and the tag immediately.

Comment: @n.1 No it's not a problem. The problem is that doctrine does insert queries, then delete queries. So it tries to insert a new tag (3, 'event') which violates uniqueness.

Comment: How the `News` and `Tag` are associated? Can you show the Doctrine2 models please? The [Symfony2 documentation explains how to add tags to an entity](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html), I suggest you to try from this point.

Comment: @n.1 it's not related to associations. I posted another example without any relationship.

Answer (score 0):

I hit this problem myself and have been trying to get my head around the why and how.

> PS: I know I can call flush twice, but it's a bad idea.

It's only a bad idea if you are trying to safely perform all DML queries in a single transaction.

Doctrine will commit DML statements in the following order:

1. All entity insertions
2. All entity updates
3. All collection deletions
4. All collection updates
5. All entity deletions

I suspect the goal behind this ordering is to satisfy FK constraints.  I.e. If you delete an entity, you need to remove all references to it first.

Where you need to perform your DML queries in a specific order, I believe you should use Transactions, as described in the Doctrine documentation at [Transactions and Concurrency](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html).

So with this method, you call `flush()` twice, but you do it within a single transaction.  The following is an example based on your tags, assuming the tag name is unique.

```
<?php

$em->beginTransaction();
try {
    $tag2 = $em->find(2);
    $tagName = $tag2->getName();
    $newTagWithSameName = new Tag($tagName);

    $em->remove($tag2);
    $em->flush();

    $em->persist($newTagWithSameName);
    $em->flush();

    $em->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $em->rollback();
    throw $e;
}
```